# How to combine dissimilar curves into a single "average"?

Tags: functional-data-analysis

With relevance to "[functional data analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_data_analysis)", I am looking for some approach which can give an intermediate function among these five different function plots, where this "average function" has the closest distance at each point on the x-axis to each of the five plots.

The plots are shown here for the purpose of the question:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Are there any particular methods one can use?

Comment: Re: "... this "average function" has the closest distance at each point on the x-axis to each of the five plots.", this is given by the function which is simply the pointwise average of your functions.

Comment: @JohnMadden Because of the log scaling of the above figures would you recommend the geometric mean for the "pointwise average"?

Comment: @JimB hahaha got me :) indeed, if you want it to be close on the log scale, we should average in logspace.

Comment: @JohnMadden Just checking to see if I was out of touch.  I gave that advice to the OP when that exact same question (but for a potential implementation in *Mathematica*) was asked at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/277880/how-can-i-find-an-intermediate-function-between-a-set-of-functions.